# How can I define the v-data-table's footer like this way?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

i know i can use v-pagination to build my own table footer
but how can i make it more complicated like what we see above?

```
   <v-data-table
      class="elevation-1"
      :headers="table.headers"
      :items="licenseLogs"
      :items-per-page="table.options.itemsPerPage"
      :no-data-text="table.options.noDataText"
      :page.sync="table.options.page"
      hide-default-footer
      @page-count="table.options.pageCount = $event"
    >
     
    </v-data-table>
<div>
      
      <v-pagination
        v-model="table.options.page"
        :length="table.options.pageCount"
      ></v-pagination>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to customize the external footer & pagination. For example...

```
       <v-row class="text-center px-4 align-center">
            <v-col class="text-no-wrap shrink">
                Total {{ totalRecords }} records
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
                <v-pagination
                    v-model="page"
                    :length="pageCount">
                </v-pagination>
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
                <v-select
                    dense
                    outlined
                    hide-details
                    :value="itemsPerPage"
                    label="Items per page"
                    @change="itemsPerPage = parseInt($event, 10)"
                    :items="perPageChoices">
                </v-select>
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="page"
                    label="Go to page"
                    outlined
                    hide-details
                    dense
                    @input="page = parseInt($event, 10)"
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
       </v-row>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/hLTD6ae1No#)

Comment: Please, accept an answer so others know the question is solved [What should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)